# Programmatically changing layers in QGIS Print Composer?

Tags: pyqgis, print-composer, qgis-2.14

I'm trying to programmatically generate new layers from a database, and then print them using a template. Using the QGIS `2.14.10x64` Python Console in Windows 7x64. I've been following on to code from [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/116071/36886) and [this one](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/222772/36886). Set up code:

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtXml import QDomDocument
from qgis.utils import iface

def load_print_composer(template):
    '''Load a print composer template from provided filename argument

    Args:
        template: readable .qpt template filename
        console: boolean if method is used in QGIS console

    Returns:
        myComposition: a QgsComposerView loaded from the provided template
        --mapSettings: a QgsMapSettings object associated with myComposition'''
    # Load template from filename
    myDocument = QDomDocument()
    with open(template, 'r') as templateFile:
        myTemplateContent = templateFile.read()
        myDocument.setContent(myTemplateContent)
    composerView = None

    composerView = iface.createNewComposer()
    composerView.composition().loadFromTemplate(myDocument)
    myComposition = composerView.composition()
    mapSettings = myComposition.mapSettings()
    return {'QgsComposition': myComposition,
            'QgsMapSettings': mapSettings,
            'QgsComposerView': composerView}

template = 'somefilename'
printcomposer = load_print_composer(template)
```

### Things that don't work

#### #1 changing `QgsMapSettings`:

```
layerlist = printcomposer['QgsMapSettings'].layers()
layer0 = layerlist.pop(0)
printcomposer['QgsMapSettings'].setLayers(layerlist)
```

#### #2 Making sure mapCanvases are linked

From [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/150951/36886)

```
map0 = printcomposer['QgsComposition'].getComposerMapById(0)
map0.renderModeUpdateCachedImage()
map0.setMapCanvas(iface.mapCanvas())
map0.layerSet()
map0.setLayerSet(layerlist)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confusing but functional, after muddling through [Setting layer visibility in QGIS Python API?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/119280/115):

```
from qgis.gui import QgsMapCanvasLayer
map_registry = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance()
names = [layer.name() for layer in map_registry.mapLayers().values()]
layerslist = [map_registry.mapLayersByName(names[0])[0],map_registry.mapLayersByName(names[1])[0]]
#what 
layerslist = [ QgsMapCanvasLayer(layer) for layer in layerslist]
iface.mapCanvas().setLayerSet(layerslist)
printcomposer['QgsComposition'].refreshItems()
```

Comment: Will update with standalone script when I get to it